# Sending Push from app id to different app id using Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am using parse.com services.

I understood how to send push notification from one app id to the same app id, works well, but i would like to create an app called " host app " which will send push notification to the app called " guest app ", how does the certification and installation work ?

2 AppID, on .p12 certificat for both, 2 application Id on parse.com ?

Moreover, can I send APN from dev app to production app ?

Thanks for helping me,

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple apps created in Xcode that use the same parse app id. You can put a column in the installation table to filter by a specific app and only send pushes to that one.